Could we revisit WebP support with the new uploader?
There's a feature request from last year requesting WebP support. I'd say the arguments made there were persuasive, and I'd encourage people to take a look at that post.
I'd say that with the new image uploader, and SE hosting images themselves, it might be a good time to revisit the feature request.

I'll add that I agree with you in spirit quite a bit; now that we own this, it's much easier to consider changesets. But also want to at least acknowledge that replacing Imgur was a good chunk of engineering effort that, by the nature of software development, deferred other priorities on the backlog. The appetite to continue enhancing it after reaching parity may not be there for all enhancements right off the bat.  Totally reasonable to ask, and we might prioritize anyway, but wanted to give some context too.

is it legit to post feature requests again like this for the new image system? that previous one isn't even [tag:status-declined]...

Thats a good question - I'd say there's a significant change in circumstances. I was considering editing, the original post, bountying or reasking, and considering that staff are actively keeping an eye out on new posts about the image uploader, and being very responsive, this felt like the best way of it being seen. From my perspective - the 'worst' that I saw happening was a duplicate close. I guess the question would be was this more effective than resurfacing the old post. In moderation, I'd say that the ends justify the means. There's minimal disruption to the network

or the site, it gives a useful feature the best chance of being implimented, and at the very least its potentially somewhere on the readmap while the image uploader is being actively developed. Its not 'strictly' the neatest solution, but sometimes you need a little chaos

@JourneymanGeek Seemingly perversely, that's being closed as a dupe of this.

Looking at the last edit - if it happens, I assume OP of the other question won't mind too much? :D

As of today, webp images are supported across all of the Stack Exchange sites. A webp image can be used in all places where images are supported — profiles, the About Me section of your profile, and, of course, Question and Answers.
As well, with webp images you can continue to use the existing means to resize images either through the thumbnails or query parameters.
One thing to note is that we do not support animated webp images.

I guess it's a "no", but what about chat onebox?

can confirm it uploads but no onebox in chat

Follow-up: Improve upload error message for animated WebP images

The feature (and the quick follow up on it not quite working on chat) is appreciated.

"As well, with webp images you can continue to use the existing means to resize images either through the thumbnails or query parameters." There seems to be a bug where WebP image thumbnails are unexpectedly converted to JPG format.

Why no animation? Requested support here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/402470/could-we-support-animated-webp-images

To SE team: I share the sentiment of others that animation support is important. Animated images can better demonstrate how to navigate through software menus or perform some specific task. They're perfect for illustrating concepts not complex enough to warrant an entire YouTube tutorial, but complex enough that still images alone would be unclear. Animated images are also useful for sharing reference animations, or showcasing animated results.

Here are some specific examples, from personal experience, of cases when being able to share an animated GIF allowed me to offer much more helpful answers: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 It would be great if we could also do this in .webp format.
