Could we support animated WebP images?
Could we please have support added for animated WebP images?
I wanted to upload an animated WebP on https://blender.stackexchange.com/.
But it turns out animated WebP images are not supported:

Improve upload error message for animated WebP images
https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/400993/1386883

Then I tried converting to a GIF. It worked, but the GIF was 10x larger than my WebP. The GIF also got scaled down to 600x600 (from 800x800). I also tried APNG, which became huge:

WebP: 388KB ✅ (original size, 800x800 ✅)
GIF, 10x larger: 3849KB ❌ (scaled down to 600x600 ❌)
APNG, 63x larger: 24,534KB ❌

I would like to humbly request support for animated WebP as well.
